# Can't get desired output while looping using VB.Net and SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following code, in which I'm trying to loop through a database, extract apartment numbers and meter readings for their heat outputs during a certain year entered by the user.

The output has to be like...

Apartment No. {apartmentNo} - {TotalReading}

Apartment No. {apartmentNo} - {Totalreading} 'second apartment number and so on

The query seems to read only the last data and not the previous ones.

This is my VB.Net code.

```vb
    Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class AssociationHeating

        Private Sub GetAssociationButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetAssociationButton.Click
            Dim con As New SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            Dim totalHeating As Integer = 0
            Dim apt_no As Integer = 1

            con.ConnectionString = "Server=10.176.165.29,1433;Database=EnergyDB;User=Clerk;Pwd=12345"
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT apartment_no,reading FROM HeatMeasurement WHERE association_no = '" & AssociationField.Text 

& "' and year(reading_date) = '" & YearField.Text & "'"
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows Then
                Do While reader.Read()
                    If Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(0)) = apt_no Then
                        totalHeating += reader.GetInt32(1)
                        'Console.WriteLine("Read data from apartment: " & reader.GetString(0))
                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("Apartment " & apt_no & " totals: " & totalHeating)
                        apt_no += 1
                        Console.WriteLine("Incremented apt_no by one")
                        totalHeating = 0
                    End If
                Loop
                Console.WriteLine("Apartment " & apt_no & " totals: " & totalHeating)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("No data found for the year " & YearField.Text)
            End If
            con.Close()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The printouts look like this:
Apartment 1 totals: 110
Incremented apt_no by one
Apartment 2 totals: 0

(There are 2 apartments with meters)

Comment: please be clear on what output you desire

Comment: The desired output would be:
Apartment 1 totals: 110 
Incremented apt_no by one 
Apartment 2 totals: 120
There are numbers in the DB for apartment 2, but it doesnt calculate them

Comment: so you want to count meter readings per apartment? are 110 and 120 the meter readings of apartments 1 and 2? is there a data of apartment numbers saved in the database?

Comment: Yes :) many chars to post comment is needed

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Control/Break logic. You see this whenever you have lots of rows that are ordered by some field with lots of the same value (in this case: `apt_no`), and you want to print header or footer entries for each value in the field.

You handle this correctly by nesting two while loops. The condition for both loops checks whether you're at the end of your data, but the inner loop also checks for when the group changes. Then you only increment the reader in the inner loop. This structure avoid duplicating any code except for the initial read of the records. It also puts the code in logical order, handling the header and initialization for a group first, then the individual records, and finally the footer for the group last.

This logic also scales easily to multiple levels of group... just add another inner loop for each additional group level.

Finally, the code below also fixes a really nasty sql injection vulnerability in the original code.

```vb
Private Sub GetAssociationButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetAssociationButton.Click
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT apartment_no,reading FROM HeatMeasurement WHERE association_no = @Association AND year(reading_date) = @Year ORDER BY apartment_no" 

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=10.176.165.29,1433;Database=EnergyDB;User=Clerk;Pwd=12345"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, con)

        'Had to guess at column types and lengths here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Association", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = AssociationField.Text 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt( YearField.Text)

        con.Open()
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           Dim rows As Boolean = reader.Read()
           If Not rows Then Console.WriteLine("No data found for the year {0}", YearField.Text)

           '------------
           'Control/Break logic
           '------------
           'Outer loop to check for end of records
           While rows 
               'Group initialization and header
               Dim apt_no As Integer = CInt(reader("apartment_no"))
               Dim totalHeating As Integer = 0
               Console.WriteLine("Read data from apartment: {0}", apt_no)

               'Inner loop checks for end of records and change of group
               While rows AndAlso aptNo = reader("apartment_no")
                    'process individual records
                    totalHeating += reader("reading")

                    'Increment record pointer
                    rows = reader.Read()
               End While
               'Group trailer/footer
               Console.WriteLine("Apartment {0} totals: {1}",apt_no, totalHeating)
           End While

           reader.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Normally nesting two loops is O(n<sup>2</sup>) or at least O(n log n), but this is still O(n) because you only read inside the inner loop, just as if you only had one loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub GetAssociationButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetAssociationButton.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim query as String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim totalHeating As Integer = 0
        Dim apt_no As Integer = 1

        con.ConnectionString = "Server=10.176.165.29,1433;Database=EnergyDB;User=Clerk;Pwd=12345"
        con.Open()
        query = "SELECT MAX(apartment_no) as maxAptNo FROM HeatMeasurement WHERE association_no = '" & AssociationField.Text & "' and year(reading_date) = '" & YearField.Text & "'")
        cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.read()
        Dim maxAptNo as integer = reader("maxAptNo")
        con.Close()

        con.Open()
        query = "SELECT apartment_no, reading FROM HeatMeasurement WHERE association_no = '" & AssociationField.Text & "' and year(reading_date) = '" & YearField.Text & "'")
        cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            Do Until apt_no = maxAptNo
                While reader.Read()
                    If Convert.ToInt32(reader("apartment_no") = apt_no Then
                        totalHeating += CINT(reader("reading"))
                    End If
                End While                    
                Console.WriteLine("Apartment " & apt_no & " totals: " & totalHeating)       apt_no+=1
                totalHeating=0
            Loop
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No data found for the year " & YearField.Text)
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

I just edited some of your codes... see if this works.
Since you were asking for the logic, I just thought of giving you this answer. Just a piece of advice, it is better to use stored procedures in your queries but for now, try this.

Comment: Line 15; cmd.Connection = con
Gives error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Client.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It also warns me: Warning 1 Variable 'cmd' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: delete it...that's not supposed to be there. sorry

Comment: Thrown: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." (System.InvalidOperationException) Exception Message = "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.", Exception Type = "System.InvalidOperationException", Exception WinRT Data = Nothing 

Occurs on line 24: reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Comment: @H4rdstyler try to close the connection before the next query... see my update